# Python does not recognize module

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
C:\Work>a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Work\a.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests

C:\Work>pip install requests
Downloading/unpacking requests
Installing collected packages: requests
Successfully installed requests
Cleaning up...

C:\Work>a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Work\a.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

Don't know why python does not recognize modules that I install.
It does the same with other modules too.

Comment: Sounds like you have multiple versions of python installed, or some other conflict.  Hard to tell for certain without more information though ... what operating system, platform, and architecture?

Comment: Yeah, i have 2.7 and 3.4 and XP x32
Now i'm uninstalling both of them and install 3.4 again to see what happens.

Comment: Try `pip2 install requests`.

Comment: +roippi: I had the same problem that that fixed it: you may need to have the module installed in both python 3 and 2

Answer (score 0):

It was because i had two versions, but it worked ok for a while, and today didn't. With only 3.4 looks ok.